# Agent admitted failure to sign using the key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

`.ssh dir` is chmodded 700, `id_rsa.pub` 600, `id_rsa` 400.

I ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, imported key to launchpad and ran `bzr branch lp:unity`, but got error message:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.
```

`auth.log`:

```
Nov 28 20:23:13 ubuntu sudo:  deltrem : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/deltrem/Documentos/repositories ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/bzr branch lp:unity
Nov 28 20:39:01 ubuntu CRON[2959]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 28 20:39:01 ubuntu CRON[2959]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 28 20:41:04 ubuntu gnome-screensaver-dialog: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
```

Comment: Are you running ssh-keygen or are you running sudo ssh-keygen?

Comment: I'm running ssh-keygen.

Comment: The user is connecting _to_ Launchpad, so neither his `auth.log` nor `authorized_keys` have anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You may need to load the key into the agent with `ssh-add`.

If you've done that, check if you're affected by one of the related Ubuntu bugs: 
[201786](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/201786),
[328127](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/328127),
[488296](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/488296).

Answer (score 0):

Following advice from this [How to solve “agent admitted failure to sign using the key” error?](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/07/tip-how-to-solve-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign-using-the-key-error/), I just logged out and back in on the client.
Everything started working just fine again.